# how to modifiy a list from ListFragment in its parent activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

I have a SherlockListFragment and I'm creating an Adapter for it inside onActivityCreated.
The parent activity implements a callback interface for communicating with its fragments. 
When a method from the activity is called I want to add / remove an item from the fragment's list. 
I have tried to use getListAdapter and I receive a NPE. If I use getListView, then a "content view not yet created" error is received. 
How can I modify the list from fragment in a correct way?

Activity code:

```
@Override
public void addFavorite(Contact item) {
    List<Contact> favoriteContacts = ((FavoriteContactsAdapter) favouriteContactsFragment
            .getListAdapter()).getContacts();
    favoriteContacts.add(0, item);
    FavoriteContactsAdapter adapter = new FavoriteContactsAdapter(
            getApplicationContext(), R.layout.contact_layout,
            favoriteContacts);
    favouriteContactsFragment.setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Fragment code:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    contacts = getArguments()
            .getParcelableArrayList(Constants.CONTACTS_KEY);

    adapter = new FavoriteContactsAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.contact_layout,
            ContactsUtils.getFavoriteContacts(contacts));
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    ...
```

Comment: post your code by editing.

Comment: post all your code dear

Comment: use callback interface method 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Done; added my relevant code

Comment: I use callback interface methods, addFavorite is one of them.